# changing theme on the fly for elements

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

Is it possible to change the theme for an element on the fly?

```
$this->theme('Theme1');
echo $this->element('Plugin.view'); // will be overiden by theme1 view
$this->theme('Theme2');
echo $this->element('Plugin.view'); // will be overiden by theme2 view
```

Comment: Have you tried your code example?

Comment: I have tried the code example and it does not work... should it work?